# Lightning Out gives 404 erors for LWC files

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I am using Lightning Out to embed a component into my NodeJS web-application. I use JWT+Connected App to authenticate users. I am able to pass different usernames and log in under different users. I show current user in my component and see that login is correct.
Everything works fine when I run it with an active SF session. But when I open an icognito window LWCs do not load and my component is not displayed. I receive 404 errors: [image]

An example of url which gives 404:

```
https://<myInstance>.lightning.force.com/l/{"mode":"PROD","app":"c:iFrameTest","serializationVersion":"1-1.9.3-230.1-b","parts":"t","loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://c:iFrameTest":"HiTtwIHvu-sRw7lPbiS19g"},"dns":"c","ls":1}/appcore.js?ltngOut=true
```

All those files are from .lightning.force.com/l/ and I do not know how to make those files publicly available.

My Site has public access. It's actually a B2B Commerce on Lightning storefront and I can browse it as a Guest User.

I tried to login not on the Site access point, but directly to the Sandbox. Nothing changed: login works fine, but the files are not available.

Here is how I authenticate and render the components on the client side:

```
axios.post(token_url, querystring.stringify(params))
    .then(function (res1:any) {         
    console.log('We got a login token');            
    console.log('res1', res1);
         conn = new jsforce.Connection({
             instanceUrl: res1.data.instance_url,
             accessToken: res1.data.access_token
         });         
    var loginResponse:any = {
    username: credentials.salesforce.username,
    accessToken: conn.accessToken,
    sfdcServerUrl: conn.instanceUrl,
    lightningServerUrl: 'https://<myInstance>.lightning.force.com',
    orgId: '00D0n0000002tNm',
    appName: "c:iFrameTest",
    lwcCmpName: "c:injectJSComponent"
    };
        console.log('We are logged in. Initializing UI...');
        res.render('pages/lout',loginResponse);
    })
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. How did you resolve it ?

Comment: An important know issue is that if you are using guest user access and you are also logged on to your experience community, you will get 404s for bootstrap and inline.js. https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ2LVAA0/lightning-out-app-implementing-ltngallowguestaccess-fails-to-load-inlinejs-and-bootstrapjs-when-the-customer-is-logged-into-his-community-app